# find all the words that contain a substring and display them in different lines

Tags: text-processing, grep

How to find all the words that contain a substring and display them in different lines?

I have this line:

```
john_ford peter_smith john_stone albert_brown john_rice john_harris lewis coll
```

I want to display all the names that start with `john_`

If I use `grep -o`:

```
echo "john_ford peter_smith john_stone albert_brown john_rice john_harris lewis coll" | grep -o john_
```

The result is:

```
john_
john_
john_
john_
```

but my desired output is:

```
john_ford
john_stone
john_rice
john_harris
```

How could I get it?, Is it necessary to use a tool like awk?

Comment: Post your solution as an Answer, not in the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: `grep -o '\b'john_'\w*'`

```
echo "john_ford peter_smith john_stone albert_brown john_rice john_harris lewis coll" |
  grep -o '\b'john_'\w*'
```